# Prove the convergence of the integral

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

I have an article to prove the following lemma, but I don't quite understand. Can you explain more?

**Lemma.** We have $N(t)=N_{\alpha_{n}}(t)=\#\lbrace n:\alpha_{n}\leq t\rbrace$. Let $\{\alpha_{n}\}$ be a positive sequence, tending to infinity. Let $ \varphi$ be a differentiable, positive, and non-increasing function on $[1,\infty)$ , such that $ \varphi (t)\rightarrow 0 $ as $t\rightarrow\infty$. Then the series $\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty \varphi(\alpha_n)$ converges if and only if $\int \limits _1^\infty \varphi^\prime (t) N(t) \Bbb dt$

**Proof**

Let $\{\alpha_{n_j}\}$ be the non-decreasing rearrangement of $\{\alpha_n \}$. Clearly, $N(t)$ is a non-decreasing, right continuous, step function with jumps appearing along a subsequence of points $\{\alpha_{n_j}\}$

Now, by the above considerations, and using the definition of Riemann-Stieltjes integral, for any $z > 1$ we have

$$ \sum_{\{k:1<\alpha_k \leq z\}} \varphi (\alpha_k) = \int \limits _1^z\varphi (t) \Bbb dN(t)=\varphi (z)N(z)-\varphi (1)N(1)-\int \limits _1^z \varphi^\prime (t) N(t) \Bbb dt .$$

Note that the last term on the right hand side has, in fact, positive sign since $\varphi$ is non-increasing.

If $\sum \limits _{k=1}^\infty \varphi (\alpha_k)<\infty$, then clearly the integral of the statement converges. If
the integral converges, by the monotonicity of $N(t)$ and the assumption $ \varphi (t)\rightarrow 0 $ as $t\rightarrow\infty$, we have

$$\varphi (z)N(z)\leq - \int \limits _z^\infty \varphi^\prime (t) N(t) \Bbb dt $$

as $z\rightarrow\infty$, hence, the series $\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty \varphi(\alpha_n)$ converges.

Comment: Hint: For every $\alpha\geqslant1$, $$\varphi(\alpha)=\int_{\alpha}^{\infty}\varphi'(t)dt=\int_{1}^{\infty}\mathbf 1_{\alpha\leqslant t}\varphi'(t)dt.$$ Now apply this to each $\alpha_n$ and sum over $n$, using the definition of $N(t)$ as $$N(t)=\sum_n\mathbf 1_{\alpha_n\leqslant t}.$$

Comment: It means $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \varphi (\alpha_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_1^\infty \textbf{1}_{\alpha_n \leq t} \varphi  \prime (t)dt = \int_1^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \textbf{1}_{\alpha_n \leq t} \varphi  \prime (t)dt =  \int_1^\infty \varphi  \prime (t) N(t)dt$?? Is this right??

Comment: Can you anwer me what "$log^+$" means??